# Active admin has many through relation issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I have 3 models

**Fruit.rb**

```
has_many :seeds, through :fruit_seed

has_many :fruit_seeds
```

**Seed.rb**

```
has_many :fruits, through :fruit_seed

has_many :fruit_seeds
```

**fruit_seed.rb**

```
belongs_to :fruit

belongs_to :seed
```

Fields in fruit seed table(fruit_id, seed_id)

Created active admin resource for fruit_seed

In that by default I can select one fruit, one seed from drop down and save.

But I need to save for one fruit has_many seeds (save seed list as an array in the joint table fruit seed) which means multi select for saving seeds array.

Explored official documentation but not Able to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your **fruit.rb** file put,

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :seeds, allow_destroy: true
```

then in activeadmin's `fruit.rb` file form,

```
form do |f|
    f.semantic_errors *f.object.errors.keys
    f.inputs "Fruit attributes" do
      f.input :title
      # your fruit model attributes
    end
    f.inputs "Fruit seeds" do
      f.has_many :seeds do |s|
        s.input :seed_name # whatever you want to take as input
      end
    end
    f.actions
end
```

If you are using rails 4+, then there will be strong parameter issue. In that case use `permit_params` in activeadmin's `fruit.rb` file

```
permit_params :fruit_name, seeds_attributes: [:id, :seed_name, :_destroy, :fruit_id]
```